# Reducing SSH connections

Tags: shell, ssh

Okay, so I have a shell script for transferring some files to a remote host using `rsync` over `ssh`.

However, in addition to the transfer I need to do some house-keeping beforehand and afterwards, which involves an additional `ssh` with command, and a call to `scp` to transfer some extra data not included in the `rsync` transfer (I generate this data while the transfer is taking place).

As you can imagine this currently results in a lot of `ssh` sessions starting and stopping, especially since the housekeeping operations are actually very quick (usually). I've verified on the host that this is show up as lots of SSH connects and disconnects which, although minor compared to the actual transfer, seems pretty wasteful.

So what I'm wonder is; is there a way that I can just open an `ssh` connection and then leave it connected until I'm done with it? i.e - my initial `ssh` housekeeping operation would leave its connection open so that when `rsync` (and afterwards `scp`) runs it can just do its thing using that previously opened connection.

Is such a thing even possible in a shell script? If so, any pointers about how to handle errors (i.e - ensure the connection is closed once it isn't needed) would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  The easiest way doesn't even require any programming.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/cant-share-an-ssh-connection-with-rsync - the general idea is to use SSH connection reuse to get your multiple SSHs to share one session, then get rsync to join in as well.

The hard way is to use `libssh2` and program everything yourself.  This will be a lot more work, and it seems in your case has nothing to recommend it.  For more complex scenarios, it's useful.